# LINQ direct cast error

Tags: vb.net, linq, casting

I am using two tables(A&B) to derive the list of items A which are not there in B.

```
Dim results1 = From table1 In dt2 Where Not (From table2 In dt1 Where DirectCast(table2(0), String) = DirectCast(table1(0), String)).Any() Select DirectCast(table1(0), String)
```

but i am getting error

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.
```

Where i need to do the conversion?

Comment: Why do you need to do a conversion at all? What are the actual types of both columns? You aren't giving us a clear question at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use 'DirectCast' here - use "table2(0).ToString()" or 'CType'.

Answer (score 1):

If you like LINQ, why not consider the entity framework. It converts your tables into strongly typed classes with your fields as the properties of the class. Adds some real simplicity when using LINQ.